# Python reflect image along each sides of the triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have created a triangle positioned in the centre of the screen.

[image]

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
GRAY = (190, 190, 190)
im = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 400), WHITE)
points = (250, 250), (100, 250), (250, 100)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.polygon(points, GRAY)
```

How do I duplicate this image and reflect it along each sides of the triangle at different random points. For example...

[image]

Comment: The first triangle is a right-angled triangle while the ones below are equilateral. Are they all supposed to be of the same type?

Comment: @pingul No it should not matter. The bit I'm having difficulty with is finding each 3 sides of the triangle and randomly placing another triangle long it.

Comment: I think I would do it by randomly selecting a point along one of the sides of the big triangle and place a smaller triangle there, and then rotate it enough so it aligns with the chosen side. Would that method work?

Comment: I think so, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plan: First find a random point on the edge of the big triangle where to put a smaller one, and then rotate it so it fits properly on the edge.

Suppose we can access the points of the triangle with something like this

```
triangle.edges[0].x, 
triangle.edges[0].y, 
triangle.edges[1].x,
etc
```

We can then find an arbitrary point by first selecting an edge, and "walk a random distance to the next edge":

```
r = randInt(3) # random integer between 0 and 2
first_edge = triangle.edges[r]
second_edge = r == 2 ? triangle.edges[0] : triangle.edges[r + 1]

## The next lines is kind of pseudo-code
r = randFloat(1)
random_point = (second_edge - first_edge)*r + first_edge
```

Our next problem is how to rotate a triangle. If you have done some algebra you might recognise this:

```
def rotatePointAroundOrigin(point, angle):
    new_point = Point()
    new_point.x = cos(angle)*point.x - sin(angle)*point.y
    new_point.y = sin(angle).point.x + cos(angle)*point.y
    return new_point
```

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

In addition to this you need to determine just how much to rotate the triangle, and then apply the function above to all of the points.

Comment: Thank you, this was a big help